# Every time I upload my (play melody-)code to the arduino and I press the button, it skips the same notes in the array. How come?

Tags: c++, arduino

I made a code where, for every time I press the button, it plays the next note in the song. But the problem is, for some reason it keeps skipping the same notes in the array.

For example (my code):

```
int mariomelody[] = {
NOTE_E5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_C5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_G5, NOTE_G4, 
//THERE ARE TWO 'NOTE_E5's BECAUSE THE THIRD NOTE DOESNT PLAY
NOTE_C5, NOTE_G4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_B5, NOTE_AS4, NOTE_A4,
NOTE_G4, NOTE_E5, NOTE_G5, NOTE_A5, NOTE_F5, NOTE_G5, NOTE_E5,
NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_B4,


//buttonPin sits at DIG. 12
int buttonPin = 12;

void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}



void loop()
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

 for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(mariomelody) / sizeof(mariomelody[0]); i++)
  {    
      while (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
      {
        tone(8, mariomelody[i], 20);
      }
      while (digitalRead(buttonPin) == LOW)
      {
      }
  }
```

Everybody knows the mario melody right. The first three notes are the same at different speeds (4 is half the speed of 8); E(4) E(4) E(8). For some reason it just skips the third `NOTE_E5` so I just put another `NOTE_E5` there and now it works "just fine".

Does anybody know why it skips the notes? Is it my code?

Comment: It seems it is skipping mariomelody[0], when you start the program pin 12 digital read will be low. and first you are checking for high, so mariomelody[0] tone will not output, it starts with maripmelody[1] when you press next time. reverse the order in the For loop, first check for LOW and then HIGH. I think it will work.

Comment: Thanks...that did the trick :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the mario melody, but anyway I think your code is wrong:

Try this:

```
void loop()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(mariomelody) / sizeof(mariomelody[0]); i++)
  {
    while (digitalRead(buttonPin) == LOW)
    {
      // wait until button is pressed
    }

    tone(8, mariomelody[i], 20);

    while (digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH)
    {
      // wait until button is released
    }          
  }
}
```